# Circuit analysis needed for capacitor discharge

Tags: transistors, capacitor

I am a beginner in electronics and going through below circuit from Radio shack workbook by Forrest Mims.
[image]

In the description I am unable to grasp how will C1 discharges through base emitter of Q1. Because my understanding is as follows

Step 1: C1 gets charged via R1 R2 as described.

[image]

Step 2: C1 is fully charged so current won't flow in that direction and causes Q1 to turn on
[image]

Step 3: This in turn turns on Q2

[image]

Step 4: Now after this, Why will C1 gets discharged through Q1 base emitter isn't Q1's Vbe already at forward voltage? Can someone please point me the complete closed loop in which C1 gets discharged? Below blue colored flow could be incorrect.

[image]

Comment: C1 charges in way +4.5v / Q2ec / C1 / Q1be so plus pole of C1 is at Q2 collector.

Comment: Then after C1 is charged to 3.8V the both transistors are immediatelly closed so Q2 collector drops rapidly to almost 0V.

Comment: During this the minus pole of C1 goes huge negative (-3.8v below ground at beginning) so  C1 holds the Q1 base closed.

Comment: C1 is slowly and continously discharged through Gnd/ spkr/ 100/ C1/R2/R1/4.5v until C1 reach -0.7v. Or another words until the Q1 base reach 0.7v. Then both transistors open again and C1 charges to 3v8 again.

Comment: Its a good question with a rather complex answer. Try this circuit with a 8 ohm resistor substituting for the loudspeaker. Does it oscillate in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The other side of capacitor is determined by Vbe, it will stay approximately at 0.7V as it is limited by the Vbe junction.

The Q2 will pull the other side capacitor from 0V to 4.5V.

So there will be current through cap and Q1 Vbe, and while one side of cap has 0.7V, the current will first discharge capacitor by pulling the speaker side to also 0.7V so cap is fully discharged, but transistors being on the speaker side is still pullled from 0.7V to 4.5V so there is actually 3.8V over the cap but charged in reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

C1 charges in way +4.5v / Q2ec / C1 / Q1be so plus pole of C1 is at Q2 collector.

Then after C1 is charged to 3.8V the both transistors are immediatelly closed so Q2 collector drops rapidly to almost 0V.

During this the minus pole of C1 goes huge negative (-3.8v below ground at beginning) so C1 holds the Q1 base closed.

C1 is slowly and continously discharged through Gnd/ spkr/ 100/ C1/R2/R1/4.5v until C1 reach -0.7v. Or another words until the Q1 base reach 0.7v. Then both transistors open again and C1 charges to 3v8 again.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, Why will "C1 charges in way +4.5v / Q2ec / C1 / Q1be so plus pole of C1 is at Q2 collector."? Isn't it get charged via R1 R2 R3 and ground because at t0 Q1 and Q2 will be OFF right?

Comment: I wasnt’ reading original. The author has oposite meaning for charging and discharging. I preffer say “charging” when cap gets positive. Anyway it is the same.